# AWS SAM Single Tennent per Customer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I am developing a serverless application on AWS, where rival companies put operational data on. I am thinking about single- / multi-tenant deployment.

From an operational standpoint having a multi-tenant application is the simplest. You have a pipeline  with a few stages (alpha, beta, gamma, prod). But this means the application code must weave the tenant ID into every piece of code. This means allot of care must be taken into consideration that one customer does not see the data of an other.

On the other hand the single-tenant approach means running one stack per customer. The upside is that each stack can be isolated with it's own IAM user and access secured on the levels of the deployment.

Doing single-tenant manually is "trivial", I can provision a stack with AWS SAM cli and give  the customer an endpoint.

Are there existing solutions to provision and keep up to date a few hundred environments?

Comment: I personally think single/multi-tenancy needs to be addressed at logical level than physical level, unless the customer explicitly requires it. for example US-GOV might ask AWS to build separate infra for them, but not an option for two banks (unless they are ready to bear the cost of it), even though they are rivals. As a service provider, a multi-tenant platform allows for the growth of platform, while minimizing the operational cost. Hope you got the point!

Comment: I explicitly left out the cost side of things. As we stand the bill for large customers' flex costs are already something in the order o 10K per month and they are willing to pay for it (at least so the pilot customers claim); so I really don't care much for the fix costs. But I must agree with you, from an operational standpoint, multi-tenant is always the simpler solution.